# I can not figure out why my text boxes are not vertically aligning to the parent div

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to make something similar to this:

[image: text veritcally alligned]

Where the 'Project Title' is centered within the total height of A [The image].

---

I am setting a `div` above `project-description` using flex:

```
.headline {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

---

```
<div class="column headline row__twenty">
    <div class="project-description">
        <h2>
            Title here
        </h2>
        <p>
            Some content for the boxes here
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

However I can not see why the `project-description` div is not veritcally aligning the item successfully.

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/g7omcucs/3/) on jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your flex-box definitions to the parent `.row` and it will work (parent of the `.row__seventy`and `.headline`).

Something like:

```
.project-wrap > article > .row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.project-wrap > article:nth-of-type(even) > .row {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Comment: I have noticed a problem. Whilst your suggestion does indeed work. Adding: `display: flex;` to the parent `.row` causes it to ignore the `float`. So all items appear on the left.

Comment: @davvv: Add `flex-direction: row-reverse`to the even rows (see my edited answer).

Comment: For some reason, your `nth-of-type(even)` does not work. Is the `>` a way of saying, only apply if .project-wrap is immediately followed by article immediately followed by .row?

Comment: @davvv: Yes the `>`selects exactly these elements as you wrote.

Comment: Thanks. This has fixed it. I am ashamed I didn't spot that. I need to break. Would you mind linking me to a good article which explains the `>` in CSS?

Comment: @davvv: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Simple_selectors under **Combinators**